# disable basicDay view in FullCalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

I have already remove the day from the header of the calendar.

What I cannot figure is how to remove the "link" on the number and the disable of the basicDay view.

I just want the user to have month and week.

[This is how my calendar looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1Vp3.png)

[This is the thing I want to disable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IvVV.png)

Comment: Can you replicate this issue in `jsfiddle` or share your code

Comment: Chech your fullcalendar's `dayClick` option

Comment: make sure you set navLinks false: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/navLinks/ . As mentioned above, also check that your dayClick event handler doesn't contain code to navigate to a new view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks @ADyson

I set the navLinks to false and it fixed it.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,basicWeek'
    },
    firstDay: 1,
    navLinks: false
});
```